# how can I rewrite, and optimize, this EMA calculation in F#

Tags: f#

this is an EMA calculation:

```
let EMA (period : int) (data : double[]) : double[] =
    let multiplier = 2.0 / (double)(period + 1)
    let output = Array.create data.Length System.Double.NaN 

    output.[period - 1] <- data.[0..period - 1] |> Seq.average
    for i in seq {period .. (data.Length - 1)} do
        output.[i] <- (data.[i] * multiplier) + (output.[i - 1] * (1. - multiplier))

    output
```

you can test it with:

```
EMA 3 [|1.;3.;4.;7.;5.;6.;9.;8.|]
```

and it gives:

```
[|NaN;Nan;2.66.;4.83;4.91;5.45;7.22;7.61|]
```

my first question is regarding the loop at the end:

```
for i in seq {period .. (data.Length - 1)} do
    output.[i] <- (data.[i] * multiplier) + (output.[i - 1] * (1. - multiplier))
```

can this be rewritten using a sequence operator?

my second question is: is there a fast F# implementation floating around? I couldn't find any.

Comment: I just ran your test example - the results were `[|nan; nan; 20.0; 30.0; 40.0; 50.0; 60.0; 70.0|]`. Are you missing something?

Comment: sorry, yes, I didn't see that I just the output and not the input in the question. I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know about *floating around*, but I did just write an EMA function yesterday. It looks like this:

```
let ema alpha vs =
    (None, vs)
    ||> Array.scan (fun prev x ->
        match prev with
        | None -> Some(x)
        | Some(s) -> Some(alpha*x + (1. - alpha)*s))
    |> Array.choose id
```

My version looks all the way back, rather than only a number of periods, as your version. If you want that behaviour instead, you could replace the state of type `float option` in my version with a `float[]`, or even implement it using the `Array.windowed` function.

Comment: By the way, it could have been implemented using `Array.mapFold` as well, but I think `Array.scan` is easier to understand.